# probability rolling die

Tags: probability, probability-theory

B rolls a die and scores the number obtained on the roll. A rolls two dice and scores the larger number of the two dice. whoever gets lager number win
 $$X=\begin{cases}
100,000&\text{A wins}\\
-x&\text{A loses}\\
0&\text{draw}\end{cases}$$

1. Find the probability A wins with $6$
2. Find the probability A wins
3. Find the probability B win
4. Find the probability of a draw
5. Find $x$ for which $E[X]=0$

for A and B 
       A   B  
1 1/36 1/6  
2 3/36 1/6  
3 5/36 1/6  
4 7/36 1/6  
 
5 1/4 1/6  
6 11/36 1/6  
the idea here for example biggest dice number that A roll is 2 so (1,2),(2,1),(2,2) so 3/36
and the rest same.

1 probability A wins at 6 : $11/36∗5/6=55/216$ 
the idea is to multiply probability A win at k and and probability B have dice number smaller than k

2 probability A win : A win at 2+A win at 3+A win at 4+ A win at 5+A win at 6
$=1/72+5/108+7/72+1/6+55/216$

probability of B win 
B win at 2+B win at 3+B win at 4+B win at 5+B win at 6 
1/216+1/54+1/24+16/216+25/216

Probability draw 
draw at 1+ draw at 2 + draw at 3+ draw at 4+ draw at 5+ draw at 6 br>
= $1/216+1/72+5/215+7/216+1/24+11/216$

5.how to find x so $E[X]=0$

I'm not quite sure for this one, but what is the relation of this question with the random variable X?
am i right?

Comment: What do you mean by the probability that $E[X]=0$?  That's not a question of probability.  It's $0$ or it isn't.

Comment: @saulspatz im sorry i need to find x in order E[X] = 0

Comment: Please edit your question to correct it.  Also, do you understand how to compute expectation?  I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: @saulspatz yes i already corrected it, but here i dont understand the relation of random variable $X$ to this question, is it to compute expectation?

Comment: @DavidK i wrote it when i first asked this question ,whoever gets larger number win ,but someone edited it and somewhat all important things is deleted :/

Comment: I have seen that problem with overzealous editing before. Doing your own MathJax helps to avoid too many other people's edits, but in the end sometimes you just have to put back the information that they delete. I see you did that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$E(X)= 100000P(A)-xP(B)$$ by definition of expectation, where $P(A)$ is the probability that $A$ wins, and $P(B)$ is the probability that $B$ wins.  You have only to substitute the values that you computed in steps 1 and 2 and solve for $x$.